# pick photo from contacts

Tags: android, contacts, photo

I want to pick photo from contacts . I got below code from stack overflow , but what are the paramaters do I need to pass for the method? Please help me

```
   public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) {

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
            InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
            if (input == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether you referred from the same link or not,but you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752653/from-phonebook-how-can-i-get-contact-number-and-photo-in-android-application).

I haven't tried this.But with reference to this link,i think,you have to pass _id of ContactsContract.Contact table.

```
Cursor cursor=getContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
long id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
```

`loadContactPhoto(getContentResolver(),id)` should be passed here as parameters.

Comment: i am also faceing the same problem of "id" what is that id...? just share with us prabhu M..

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to get contact image , number and email address.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.bean.MemberBean;
import com.example.db.AppDBManager;
public class AddContactActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button _chooseContactButton, _submitButton;
    EditText name, number, email, relation;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    ImageView _contactPic;
    String imagePath = "",Name="",Number="",Relation="",emailid="";
    private Uri fileUri;
    private Uri uriContact;
    private String contactID;
    public static String localNumber=null;
    private PopupWindow myPopupWindow=null;
    File photo;
    String _imageUrl="";
    String  _imageUrl1;
    String _time="";
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private static final int SELECT_CONTACT = 2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        _chooseContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        _submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        relation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
       _contactPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       _contactPic.setOnClickListener(this);
       _chooseContactButton.setOnClickListener(this);
       _submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
      int millisecond = cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
      int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
      int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      int hourofday = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
     _time="image_"+hourofday+""+minute+""+second+""+millisecond;
     Intent intent=getIntent();
      Name =intent.getStringExtra("name");
      Number =intent.getStringExtra("mobile");
      localNumber=intent.getStringExtra("mobile");
      Relation =intent.getStringExtra("relation");
      emailid =intent.getStringExtra("email");
     _imageUrl1 =intent.getStringExtra("image");
      name.setText(Name);
      number.setText(Number);
      relation.setText(Relation);
      email.setText(emailid);
      if(_imageUrl1!=null)
      {
          if(_imageUrl1.length()==0) {
              _contactPic .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_b);
          }
          else{
                Drawable d=BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(_imageUrl1);
                _imageUrl=_imageUrl1;
                _contactPic.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
          }
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View V) {
        if (V.equals(_chooseContactButton)) {

            Intent nyintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(nyintent, SELECT_CONTACT);
        } else if (V.equals(_submitButton)) {
            if (isInputValid()) {
                String Name = name.getText().toString();
                String Number = number.getText().toString();
                String Relation = relation.getText().toString();
                String emailid = email.getText().toString();
                AppDBManager dbManager = new AppDBManager(this);
                dbManager.openDatabase();
                MemberBean member = new MemberBean();
                member.setName(Name);
                member.setMobile(Number);
                member.setRelation(Relation);
                member.setEmail(emailid);
                member.setImage(_imageUrl);
                dbManager.insertMember(member);
                dbManager.closeDatabase();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListShow.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        } else if (V.equals(_contactPic)) {
             final View myPopupView; myPopupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.pickgallerychooser, null);
             myPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(myPopupView,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            myPopupWindow.showAtLocation(myPopupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            ImageButton gallery = (ImageButton) myPopupView
                    .findViewById(R.id.gallery_button);
            ImageButton camera = (ImageButton) myPopupView
                    .findViewById(R.id.camera_button);

            gallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myPopupWindow.dismiss();
                    Intent nyintent = new Intent();
                    nyintent.setType("image/*");
                    nyintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(nyintent, "Select Picture"),
                            SELECT_PICTURE);

                }
            });
            camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myPopupWindow.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,
                            CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {          
          _contactPic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageview_background);
        try {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                 uriContact = data.getData();
                 email.setText("");
                 number.setText("");
                 name.setText("");
                 retrieveContactNumber();
                 retrieveContactPhoto();
                 retrieveContactName();
            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if ((requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)) {
                    //select gallery
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    Drawable drawable ;
                    _imageUrl = filePath;
                     drawable = BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(filePath);
                    _contactPic.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                }
            } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE
                    && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                //camera picture
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(thumbnail);
                _contactPic.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                saveBitmap(thumbnail);              
         }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void retrieveContactPhoto() {
        Bitmap photo = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts
                    .openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                            ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                    new Long(contactID)));
            if (inputStream != null) {
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(photo);
                _contactPic.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                 Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
                 File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
                 _imageUrl=finalFile.getAbsoluteFile().toString();
                 Log.e("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","url is"+_imageUrl);
            }
            assert inputStream != null;
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void retrieveContactNumber() {
        String contactNumber="";
        Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null,
                null);

        if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {
            contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        }

        cursorID.close();
        Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },

                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND "
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = "
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                new String[] { contactID }, null);
        int ColumeIndex_HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.e("sanjay ", "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"+ColumeIndex_HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);

        if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
            contactNumber = cursorPhone
                    .getString(cursorPhone
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        cursorPhone.close();
        number.setText(contactNumber);

    }
    private void retrieveContactName() {
        String contactName = null;
        String email1 = null;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null,null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        cursor.close();
        name.setText(""+ contactName);
        Cursor emailcur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contactID}, null);
        while (emailcur.moveToNext()) {
                  email1 = emailcur.getString(emailcur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

        }   
        emailcur.close();
        email.setText(email1);
    }
    private Boolean isInputValid() {
        Boolean isValid = true;
        Name = name.getText().toString();
        Number = number.getText().toString();
        Relation = relation.getText().toString();
        emailid = email.getText().toString();
        if (Name.length() == 0) {
            isValid = false;
            name.requestFocus();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (Number.length() == 0) {
            isValid = false;
            number.requestFocus();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Contact Person Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (Relation.length() == 0) {
            isValid = false;
            relation.requestFocus();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Relation of Person", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (emailid.length() == 0) {
            isValid = false;
            email.requestFocus();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Valid Email Id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if ((!emailid.contains("@")  || !emailid.contains(".")) || !(emailid.lastIndexOf("@")<emailid.lastIndexOf(".")) || !(emailid.lastIndexOf("@")==emailid.indexOf("@"))|| emailid.contains(" ")) {
            isValid = false;
            email.requestFocus();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Valid Email Id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return isValid;
    }
    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, null, null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        return cursor.getString(idx); 
    }
    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/DCIM";
          try
          {
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if(!dir.exists())
               dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, _time);
            _imageUrl=file.getAbsolutePath();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("errr in ","inserting the image at parictular location");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        if(intent.getStringExtra("value")!=null)
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else if(myPopupWindow!=null && myPopupWindow.isShowing())
        {
            myPopupWindow.dismiss();
        }
        else
        {
             AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddContactActivity.this);
             alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm ?");
             alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("It will close the application.\nDo you want to continue")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    finish();
                }})
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {    
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();     
       }
    }
}
```